What does it mean that concubinage does not establish Ihsan for a slave-girl and her master?
Is it correct that there is a consensus that the chastity of a slave girl and her master is not established and even if she gives birth to children of her master unlike where chastity of husband and wife is established due to Nikah?
[١٢٠/ ٢] التسري لا يحصل به إحصان للسيد، ولا إحصان للأمة.

موسوعة الإجماع في الفقه الإسلامي

(Note: I have provided heading only under which whole matter of ijma is discussed in the source)
Though In Qur'an Allah says

And they who guard their private parts.
Except from their wives or those their right hands possess, for indeed, they will not be blamed -

Surah Muminoon 5-6


Correct me If I understood it wrong

The point of the question is unclear to me. The linked text does cite sources and explains the issue adequately.  إحصان (which you translate as chastity) might be better translated as 'being married\non-virgin' as the issue being discussed is about whether a person qualifies for receiving the Hadd of Rajm (stoning to death) for Zina instead of whipping. The rule being discussed is that a person who was not married but had a concubine is not considered Muhsan and hence will not be stoned if he commits zina after that.

@UmH My question was "Is chastity established ie master and slave girls are called chaste just like husband and wife?
Anyways I think I mistranslated the word "Ihsan"

Whether or not they are chaste depends on what whether or not they refrain from zina. A husband\wife can be chaste or unchaste, and a master\concubine can also be chaste or unchaste depending on their deeds. The text you have asked about is not about chastity but about the prerequisite of Ihsan for enforcing the Hadd of Rajm. If you are asking about the latter then that matter is already answered on your linked page.

@UmH جزاك اللهُ خيراً
For clarification!

In Islamic law a person who commits Zina is to be whipped 100 times (Quran 24:2). However if the perpetrator has committed fornication while being married then his\her sin is even more serious and he\she is to be stoned to death:

أتى رجل رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم وهو في المسجد فناداه فقال يا رسول الله إني زنيت‏.‏ فأعرض عنه، حتى ردد عليه أربع مرات، فلما شهد على نفسه أربع شهادات، دعاه النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم فقال ‏ أبك جنون .‏ قال لا‏.‏ قال ‏‏ فهل أحصنت ‏‏‏.‏ قال نعم‏.‏ فقال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏‏ اذهبوا به فارجموه ‏
A man came to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) while he was in the mosque, and he called him, saying, "O Allah's Apostle! I have committed illegal sexual intercourse."
The Prophet (ﷺ) turned his face to the other side, but that man repeated his statement four times, and after he bore witness against himself four times, the Prophet (ﷺ) called him, saying, "Are you mad?" The man said, "No."
The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Are you married?" The man said, "Yes." Then the Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Take him away and stone him to death."
— Bukhari


لا يحل دم امرئ مسلم إلا رجل زنى بعد إحصانه أو كفر بعد إسلامه أو النفس بالنفس
It is not permissible to shed the blood of a Muslim, except a man who committed adultery after being married, or one who reverted to Kufr after becoming Muslim, or a life for a life.'
— Nasai

Ihsan (إحصان) means the state of 'being married'. It should be obvious that here it does not mean the state of 'being chaste' since by definition one who has committed zina is not chaste.
Ihsan involves being married at least once, in a valid nikah, having consummated that marriage by penetration of the penis into the vagina and by performing the coitus at a time when it was lawful (i.e., not during menstruation or ihram). If someone has experienced this, they have experienced a halal marriage to completion. If they later commit zina, it is considered a grave offense, and the legal penalty for them is execution.
Engaging in concubinage does not qualify as being married. Concubinage has some similarities to marriage but it also has differences and there are matters resulting from marriage that do not result from concubinage, see the latter half of my answer here.
The quote says:

التسري لا يحصل به إحصان للسيد، ولا إحصان للأمة

It should be translated as:

Concubinage does not achieve Ihsan for the master nor for the slave-girl

If you continue to read the text it goes on to explains what is being said:

بيان الصورة للمسألة: سبق أن من ارتكب ما يوجب الحد، فإن من شرط كونه محصنًا ليقام عليه حد الرجم أن يكون قد وطئ في نكاح صحيح، وهاتان المسألتان هما أمثلة لتخلُّف هذا الشرط، فمن وطئ أمته فإنه لا يكون محصنًا، لأنه لم يطأها في نكاح، وكذا المرأة المملوكة التي وطئها سيدها الحر فلا تصير محصنة بوطء سيدها لها
Explanation of the issue: If someone commits an offense requiring the hadd punishment, one of the conditions for them to be considered "muhsan" in order for the punishment of Rajm (stoning  to death) to be applied is that they must have previously engaged in sexual intercourse within a valid marriage. These two cases are examples of situations where this condition is not met: For if a man has intercourse with his slave woman, he is not considered "muhsan" because he did not marry her; similarly, a slave woman who has intercourse with her free master does not become a "muhsanah" by virtue of that act

Hence, if a fornicator has previously experienced concubinage but not marriage, they do not receive the punishment of stoning to death for their fornication. Instead, they are only subject to 100 lashes. That is because they do not fulfill the prerequisites for the more severe penalty to be enforced.
